# Problema para encontrar o menor valor

Tags: python

Boa noite, estou com problemas para exibir o menor valor no meu código. O enunciado é:

Desenvolver um programa para verificar a nota do aluno em uma prova com 10 questões, o programa deve perguntar ao aluno a resposta de cada questão e ao final comparar com o gabarito da prova e assim calcular o total de acertos e a nota (atribuir 1 ponto por resposta certa). Após cada aluno utilizar o sistema deve ser feita uma pergunta se outro aluno vai utilizar o sistema. Após todos os alunos terem respondido informar:

Maior e Menor Acerto;
Total de Alunos que utilizaram o sistema;
A Média das Notas da Turma

Meu código:

```
from termcolor import  colored
tot = total_alunos = maior = valor = menor = 0
while True:
    tot = 0
    for c in range(1, 11):
        resp = input('Resposta da {}° questão: '.format(c)).strip().upper()
        if c == 1:
            gabarito = 'A'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 2:
            gabarito = 'B'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 3:
            gabarito = 'C'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 4:
            gabarito = 'D'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 5:
            gabarito = 'E'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 6:
            gabarito = 'E'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 7:
            gabarito = 'D'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 8:
            gabarito = 'C'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 9:
            gabarito = 'B'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 10:
            gabarito = 'A'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        if tot > maior:
            maior = tot
        if tot < menor:
            menor = tot
    print(f'Você acertou no total {tot} questoes e sua nota foi {tot} pontos')
    total_alunos = total_alunos + 1
    media = valor / total_alunos
    continuar = ''
    while continuar != 'S' and continuar != 'N':
        continuar = input('Você deseja continuar? [S/N]: ').upper().strip()[0]
        if continuar not in 'SN':
            print(colored('ERRO! Digite novamente', 'red'), end=' ')
    if continuar == 'N':
        break
print(f'O maior foi {maior} o menor foi {menor}')
print(f'O total de alunos que utilizaram o sistema foi {total_alunos}')
print(f'A média da turma foi {media}')
```

Comment: Primeiramente, Feliz natal rs.
A sua pergunta esta um pouco confusa, tente ser mais claro e explicar melhor a situação, coloque o resultado que esta obtendo e assim fica mais fácil de ajudar, pelo que percebi você esta aprendendo ainda, mas caso ja saiba, aconselharia o uso de lista para armazenar os resultados e até para reduzir o tamanho de seu __for__

Answer (score 0):

Acho que entendi o seu problema

ele esta presente nessa parte

```
if tot < menor:
    menor = tot
```

ele verifica se o `total` é menor que `menor` sendo que o `menor` é igual a `0`, então na verdade ele nunca sera dado como `True`

o que você pode fazer?

```
if menor == maior == 0:
    menor = maior = tot
elif tot > maior:
    maior = tot
elif tot < menor:
    menor = tot
```

e remova essa parte do seu código de dentro do seu `for`

para ficar mais fácil de entender, deixarei o código completo abaixo

```
from termcolor import colored
tot = total_alunos = maior = valor = menor = 0
while True:
    tot = 0
    for c in range(1, 11):
        resp = input('Resposta da {}° questão: '.format(c)).strip().upper()
        if c == 1:
            gabarito = 'A'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 2:
            gabarito = 'B'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 3:
            gabarito = 'C'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 4:
            gabarito = 'D'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 5:
            gabarito = 'E'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 6:
            gabarito = 'E'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 7:
            gabarito = 'D'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 8:
            gabarito = 'C'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 9:
            gabarito = 'B'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
        elif c == 10:
            gabarito = 'A'
            if resp == gabarito:
                tot += 1
                valor += 1
    if menor == maior == 0:
        menor = maior = tot
    elif tot > maior:
        maior = tot
    elif tot < menor:
        menor = tot
    print(f'Você acertou no total {tot} questoes e sua nota foi {tot} pontos')
    total_alunos += 1
    media = valor / total_alunos
    continuar = ''
    while continuar != 'S' and continuar != 'N':
        continuar = input('Você deseja continuar? [S/N]: ').upper().strip()[0]
        if continuar not in 'SN':
            print(colored('ERRO! Digite novamente', 'red'), end=' ')
    if continuar == 'N':
        break
print(f'O maior foi {maior} o menor foi {menor}')
print(f'O total de alunos que utilizaram o sistema foi {total_alunos}')
print(f'A média da turma foi {media}')
```